# Finding leftmost in a family class

Tags: python, python-3.x

No matter what I changed, my code always outputs the rightmost leaf name, not the left.

I've tried adjusting the order and using different techniques, but nothing seems to change it. I know the problem is in the bottom of the code however.

Here's my code:

```
class Family:
    """Store information about the Family of a person."""
    name: str
    children: List['Family']
    def __init__(self, name: str, children: List['Family']):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Family('{}', {})".format(self.name, self.children)


def leftmost(fam: Family) -> str:
    """Return the leftmost child in fam."""
    if fam.children == []:
        return fam.name
    else:
        m = []
        farthestleft = []
        for name in fam.children:
             if len(name.children) >= len(farthestleft):
                farthestleft = name.children
                fam.name = name
        m = leftmost(name)
        return m

tully = Family('Hoster',
                 [Family('Lysa',
                         [Family('Robin', [])]),
                  Family('Edmure', []),
                  Family('Catelyn',
                         [Family('Robb', []),
                          Family('Sansa', []),
                          Family('Arya', []),
                          Family('Bran', []),
                          Family('Rickon', [])])])
check.expect("L1", leftmost(tully), "Robin")
```

The check expect returns Rickon, not Robin.

Comment: can you include the code to create a few of your family objects and what you are expecting to get when you run the code on that example data?

Comment: @scotscotmcc I updated it